# What's the name for those cards some companies use to promote customer fidelity?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request, expressions

I'm wondering if there's an expression for those cards (not necessarily a bank card), that some companies use to promote customers' fidelity, by giving out promotions, etc?

I was thinking of using the expression fidelity card. Is it okay?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Those are usually called 'loyalty cards', and they're part of a ['loyalty program'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loyalty_program).

Comment: Note they are also referred to by the company that issued the card.  A Loyalty card from Safeway could be called a "Safeway Card," from Costco a "Costco Card," etc.

Answer (score 3):

While *loyalty card* (as suggested by Glorfindel) is probably the correct generic term, the companies themselves often call them ***club cards***, as if having one makes you a member of some exclusive club.